# An Infallible cannot commit sin but can he make a mistake?

Tags: shiism, sin, infallability

I know infallible means a person who doesn’t commit any sin.
But I wonder if it is related to the mistake as well?
Actually I mean is it possible for an infallible to make any mistake?
(Since I assume there is a difference between sin and mistake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                                    بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

According to the view of Allamah Tabatabai as a famous scholar of Shiite school of thought:

> the meaning of “Infallible” is the presence of the quality in the
>   infallible human that protect him/her from doing what isn't
>   permissible, for instance "Sin or Error". {1}

Therefore it is inferred from his speech that the infallibility is related to the error (mistake) too.

For further information regarding the mentioned matter, you can refer to the following source which has some points about the word “infallible” (from Ayatollah Javadi Amoli and Jafar Sobhani) (Shia View)

**Sources:**

[islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1885)

{1} : S. Mohammad Husein Tabatabai, Al-Mizan fi Tafsir-al-Quran, v.2, pg.134 (The infallibility of the imams)

Comment: Allah repremanded Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) on his mistake when he turned away from a blind man (http://quran.com/80). How would you explain this mistake, if infallible includes protection from mistakes too? If you say that the mistake was corrected and thus nullified, then, who and how will this mistakes be corrected for Imams, as there will be no more divine revelation like Quran?

Comment: @goto Some of the commentators believe that this verse is not about the prophet (PBUH), some others say that this verse is about him and still it is not in contradiction with his position of infallibility because this was not wrong. In fact they believe this was a lapse not a mistake.

Comment: What would be the difference between a lapse and a mistake? From the verses of Quran it is evident that he (PBUH) deliberately ignored the blind man

Comment: @goto Lapse is to leave a better thing and doing sth which is not sin and mistake. However, it is an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

**بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم**

In the name of Allah the merciful the compassionate

Shi'ite scholars relate this narration of the Prophet (PBUH):

> "إني تارك فيكم الثقلين كتاب الله وأهل بيتي وإنهما لن يفترقا حتى يردا
>   عليّ الحوض."
>
> Verily, I am leaving among you Two Weighty Things: the Book of Allah
>   (the Qur’an) and the members of my Household {Ahl al-Bayt}, and they
>   will never separate from each other until they meet me at the Pond
>   {Al-Hawd} (of Kawthar on the Day of Resurrection)

All the Muslims believe, The noble Qur'an is free from any mistakes, errors or deviations. because the Sender (Allah), the messenger (Revelation angel) and the receiver (the Prophet [PBUH]) are free from mistakes and errors. So the how can the Ahl-ul Bayt be considered equal to the noble Qur'an while they are not immune from errors, mistakes and deviation?

Moreover, it is mentioned in this hadith that **"they will never separate from each other"** which emphasizes on this fact.

Comment: Mustadrak al-Hakim, vol. 3, p. 148; As-Sawa‘iq al-Muhriqah, Book 11, Chapter 1, p. 149. are sunni sources.

Comment: Explicitly calling out *Sunni* sources to prove a *Shi'ite* perspective is a tactic used by polemic sites, and has no place here.  See relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1398/22

Answer (score 0):

An innocent person can not commit a sin, but can he make a mistake?
Infallibility has two stages: "Infallibility from sin" and "Infallibility from error"; The prophets endure the manifestation of sins and never make mistakes. One of the most important factors in the infallibility of the prophets against sins is "knowledge of the consequences and effects of sins". If a person has definite knowledge about the consequences of sin, he will be insured against sin.

Ref: https://www.hawzahnews.com/news/417093/%DA%86%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%AF%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%87-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%87-%D9%87%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%AF